# How to shift the control to next node of Treeview using visual basic

Tags: vb6

How to shift the control to next node of Treeview using visual basic. if clicked on button named as "NEXT", then the cursor should shift to down ward node of treeview. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use the index property

```
If Not tvw.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
    If (tvw.SelectedItem.Index < tvw.Nodes.Count) Then
        With tvw.Nodes(tvw.SelectedItem.Index + 1)
            .Selected = True
            .Expanded = True
            .EnsureVisible
        End With
    End If
End If
```